# Why does setting a custom class's __array_priority__ above zero make comparison with numpy.float64 work incorrectly?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a silly subclass of `float`:

```
class Bar(float):
    __array_priority__ = 2
```

Now we try to compare an instance of `Bar` with a numpy float64:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.float64(1)
y = Bar(2.0)
x < y
False
```

Puzzled, we try the following

```
import numpy as np

def make_class(x):
    """Get a float subclass with adjustable __array_priority"""
    class Bar(float):
        __array_priority__ = x

    return Bar


def test(priorities):
    """Check float comparison for various __array_priority__ values"""
    results = []
    for priority in priorities:
        x = np.float64(1)
        Bar = make_class(priority)
        y = Bar(2.0)
        results.append(x < y)
    for p, v in zip(priorities, results):
        print("{} {}".format(p, v))
```

Running `test` over a few choice values we find (note that the `__array_priority__` of `np.float64` is `-1000000.0`)

```
__array_priority__   |     x < y
--------------------------------------------------
-10000000            |     True
-1000001.0           |     True
-1000000.0           |     True (same __array_priority__ as float64)
-999999.0            |     True
-1                   |     True
0                    |     True
0.3                  |     False
1                    |     False
2                    |     False
```

As you can see, if `__array_priority__` is greater than `0`, the comparison fails.
Whether our custom `__array_priority__` is greater or less than `np.float64`'s `__array_priority__` doesn't matter.

Some of my colleagues tried this on their machines and we found that this problem only happens with python `2.7.6` (64 bit) and numpy `1.9.2`.
Using *either* that python version *or* that numpy version alone does not reproduce the bug.
It only happens when both of those versions are used together.

Why does setting the custom `__array_priority__` above or below `0` change the behavior of the comparison, making it work unexpectedly in the `>0` cases on this combination of python and numpy versions?

Note that replacing the `x < y` comparison with `y > x` results in expected behavior as @György Solymosi mentioned below.

Comment: There isn't much mention of `__array_priority__` in the documentation or numpy code.  Mostly it is used in `ufunc` to let `ndarray` subclasses determine what kind of array is returned.  `ndarray` has priority 0, `matrix` has priority 10.  `dtypes` presumably have a negative priority so they don't trump `ndarray` in situations like this.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree with everything you say. Unfortunately this doesn't shed light on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the comparison from `x < y` to `y > x` makes it work.

This may be related to a [known issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4766).

Comment: Do you realize that in the line `Bar = Bar().bar` you are assigning a bound method to `Bar`? Then you're setting `y` to the float 2.0 because that bound method just returns whatever you pass into it.

Comment: In my case `Bar()` returns `0.0` because it's calling the constructor of `float` with no arguments. It's exactly the same thing as if you do `float()`.

Comment: Yes, it works that way, but that doesn't answer my question. The problem is that it doesn't work with `x < y`.

Comment: This is a known bug,  when you click on the link in my answer.
**NumPy ignores __array_priority__ when the right-hand-side operand is a subclass of ndarray**

Comment: I missed the link since most of the answer is a copy-paste from the question. It would be more clear to just indicate that the `y > x` case works and make the link more obvious :)

Comment: I haven't yet time, but I do. :)

Comment: I'm also confused because the issue in your link refers to the case where the right hand operand is an `ndarray` subclass. In my example the right hand operand is not an `ndarray` subclass; it's a `float` subclass.

Comment: Yes, yes it seems it is a more general bug, then they thought.

Comment: @DanielSank Anyway I would be happy, if you would be so kind and for my research - and for my upvote, you would at least pull back your downvote even if you cannot accept my answer. :)

Comment: I submitted an edit to the answer. Let's see if it gets accepted.

Comment: @DanielSank Accepted, though the example output made the answer more clear, I think,  for others .

Comment: What's the point to setting the `__array_priority__` of a `float` subclass?  Do the base `dtypes` use anything other than -1000000?  And why set it higher than the priority for `ndarry`?

Comment: @hpaulj That's a good question and I don't know the answer. Unfortunately I didn't write the code in question. I already contacted the author and will find out soon.